# Issue Selecting Top 10 Words, While Having Conditional Block Word List

Tags: python, loops, count

Credit for original code: [10 ,most frequent words in a string Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327303/10-most-frequent-words-in-a-string-python)

Issue: Using the solution source code provided by Nikhil Gupta in the link above, how can I create a word counter which excludes words in a csv file (The csv will contain words such as "or, as, is, and...").

Goal: Iterate a job description by:

1. count each unique word
2. exclude unnecessary words from a csv to determine most used keywords in job description

How I attempted this with Nikhil Gupta's original code for a job description I saved in sample.txt (My changes are noted to the right of his code - 2 changes):

```
words = open('sample.txt').read().lower().split() # Changed .txt

# Get the set of unique words.
excluded = ['qualifications'] # Change 1 of 2
uniques = []
for word in words:
  if word not in excluded: # Change 2 of 2
    uniques.append(word)

print(uniques)

# Make a list of (count, unique) tuples.
counts = []
for unique in uniques:
  count = 0              # Initialize the count to zero.
  for word in words:     # Iterate over the words.
    if word == unique:   # Is this word equal to the current unique?
      count += 1         # If so, increment the count
  counts.append((count, unique))

counts.sort()            # Sorting the list puts the lowest counts first.
counts.reverse()         # Reverse it, putting the highest counts first.
# Print the ten words with the highest counts.
for i in range(min(10, len(counts))):
  count, word = counts[i]
  print('%s %d' % (word, count))
```

My results using his original code to test output:
[image]
My results using my changes: [image]

So print in my changes is doing what I expected by excluding the word 'qualifications' (will be replaced with a word list in csv. Words such as: or, as, and... etc). However it now reproduces 'and 19' several times, instead of the top 10 (excluding the word 'qualifications'). Can't figure out how to fix this.

All suggestions would be appreciated.
-Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is you are not finding the unique words.
so do this thing:

```
uniques=[]
for word in words:
  if word not in excluded and word not in uniques: # Change 2 of 2
    uniques.append(word)
```

Answer (score 1):

Counter from the collections module in the standard library is made for this exact thing, but requires some massaging. I did this by converting it to a dictionary, then a tuple of tuples. The sorted method with the reverse parameter set to True will kill two birds with one stone, but you have to specify the key as the index of 1.

```
### import Counter
from collections import Counter

### Dummy values in exclusion
excluded = ['foo','bar','baz']

### dummy values in words
words = ['foo','bop','foo','bar','bop','cop','cap','cap']

### Use counter to count, convert to dictionary then tuple of tuples
counts = tuple(dict(Counter([word for word in uniques if word not in excluded])).items())

### sort using sorted with reverse parameter = True
counts = sorted(counts, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

### unpack tuples and Print 
for word, count in counts:
    print(word,':',count)
```